# run time change of custom class in xib

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I would like to change at run time the custom class as defined in a xib identity inspector.
This is to avoid to define lots of xib and view controller.
I've not found anything related to that subject.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `MyCustomUIViewController` that would inherit from `UIViewController`. And set that controller as the file's owner of your XIB. This controller will have to support the defualt XIB IBOutlet and IBActions.

Then make other controllers (MyCustomUIViewControllerForThis, MyCustomUIViewControllerForThat, ...) inherit from `MyCustomUIViewController`

Then when you load it, that should give something like :

```
MyCustomUIViewControllerForThat* controller = [[MyCustomUIViewControllerForThat] alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNib" bundle:nil];
```

This way, you can define in your XIB wanted Outlets and actions, and customize them if wanted in your MyCustomUIViewControllerForThat class.